# GeoTIF becomes super large by joining two grid bands (geotiff)

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing

I have two raster tapes (GeoTIFs) that I want to merge into one GeoTIF with two bands. I used this command in the shell: `gdal_merge.py -separate -o myoutput.tif *.cropped.tif`, which was shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46761/create-subsetted-multiband-image-from-multiple-files-using-gdal-or-python).

The original GeoTIFs had a size of about 200 MG each, the merged GeoTIF had a size of 6 GB.

Does anyone have an idea what this might be about and what I can do to reduce the size?

Comment: Probably original tifs were compressed. Set compress creation option(-co switch) for gdal_merge.py. COMPRESS=[JPEG/LZW/PACKBITS/DEFLATE/CCITTRLE/CCITTFAX3/CCITTFAX4/LZMA/ZSTD/LERC/LERC_DEFLATE/LERC_ZSTD/WEBP/NONE. You can use gdalinfo myoutput.tif to see compression and other info about the source and result tifs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a new GeoTiff Gdal takes no account of how the input tiff was processed and writes your new file out as raw data.

You need to add some [creation options](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options) to compress and tile it. See Paul Ramsey's [compression for dummies](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html) for more details.

```
gdal_merge.py -co COMPRESS=deflate -co TILED=YES -separate -o myoutput.tif *.cropped.tif
```